# How to keep track of the elapsed time in a tick method?

Tags: java, timer, countdown, nanotime

In a tick() method, you can't have an *int startTime = System.nanoTime()* because it will constantly be updating it.

I need to find the **elapsed time within the tick method**, so that every 2 seconds a new object gets spawned.

```
public void tick() {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        // wave 1
        if (wave == 1) {

            float k = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            /* won't work because "startTime" is constantly updating */

            if (k >= 2 && k <= 3) {
                handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy());
            } else if (k >= 4 && k <= 5) {
                handler.addObject(new BasicObject());
            } else if (k >= 6 && k <= 7) {
                handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy());
            }
        }

        // wave 2
        if (wave == 2) {

            float k = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            /* won't work because "startTime" is constantly updating */

            if (k >= 2 && k <= 3) {
                handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy());
            } else if (k >= 4 && k <= 5) {
                handler.addObject(new BasicObject());
            } else if (k >= 6 && k <= 7) {
                handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a small snippet of the code.
How would I go about finding the **elapsed time in the tick method** and having it restart its count for every if statement?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you using threads? I don't see any threads in your code...

Comment: @px06 I only have one thread in my main class, am I supposed to have more to get this to work?

Comment: "/* won't work because "startTime" is constantly updating */" What makes you think that?  `startTime` will always be the `nanoTime()` at the start of the method, not the _current_ `nanoTime()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to hold the `timeAtLastAccept` outside the `tick()` method like so:

```
long timeAtLastAccept = System.nanoTime();
public void tick(){
    if(System.nanoTime()-timeAtLastAccept >threshold) {
         //Spawn your objects!
         timeAtLastAccept = System.nanoTime();
    } 

    //do ticky things
}
```

Comment: I did that initially, however, it continuously spawns the object every 2 seconds.

Comment: @badProgrammer if you update your time variable after it spawns an object as shown above.  It should wait another 2 seconds before spawning another

Comment: When you say "You would need to hold the timeAtLastAccept outside the tick() method", the only place I can initialise it would be in the constructor.

And if I make the threshold = 2, _System.nanoTime()-timeAtLastAccept_ will always be larger than the threshold.

Comment: @badProgrammer you have to do the calculations to convert 2 seconds to however many nanoseconds and that would be your threshold

And yes I do mean to make it a property of the class and init inside of constructor

Comment: @badProgrammer Great! If it worked out for you, you can clicked the accepted checkmark next to the voting section of my post if you'd like